# How to access Hadoop counters values via API?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, counter

In Hadoop we can increment counter in map/reduce task, it looks  like this:

```
...
context.getCounter(MyCountersEnum.SomeCounter).increment(1);
...
```

Than you can find their value in log.

How do you access them from code after job completes?

What is Hadoop API to read counter value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer [here](http://diveintodata.org/2011/03/15/an-example-of-hadoop-mapreduce-counter/).

You need a job object to access the counters:

```
Counters counters = job.getCounters();
Counter counter = counters.findCounter(MyCountersEnum.SomeCounter);
System.out.println(counter.getDisplayName() + ": " + counter.getValue());
```

Answer (score 6):

Counters represent **global counters**, defined either by the Map-Reduce framework or applications.

Each Counter can be of any Enum type.
You can define counter as an enum in Driver class

```
static enum UpdateCount{
  CNT
 }
```

And then increment the counter in map/reduce task

```
public class CntReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text>{
 public void reduce(IntWritable key,Iterable<Text> values,Context context)  {
      //do something
      context.getCounter(UpdateCount.CNT).increment(1);
 }
}
```

and access them in Driver class

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
 .
 .
 .
 job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
 job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
 FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,in );
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
 job.waitForCompletion(true);
 c = job.getCounters().findCounter(UpdateCount.CNT).getValue();
 //Print "c"
 }
}
```

**c** gives the counter value.

You can find an example [**here**](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/09/how-to-set-counters-in-hadoop-mapreduce.html)